# MySQL returning different value based on GEO location?

Tags: php, mysql

I have several pages that access my data-base directly and get values from a table.

Now depending on the users Geo location, we want to return a different value.

I have a PHP script that gets the geo location, but I am trying to figure out a way to avoid tracking down every page that accesses the data-base to add this logic.

I realize if the site was using an MVC architecture I could just add the logic to the model. Unfortunately that is not the case.

So my question is, is my only option to add this logic to every page that accesses that data from the DB. Or is there a better way I am unaware of?

*P.S. My question title probably isn't the best description of my problem but I was unsure how to word it.*

Comment: Every page that accesses the db needs to connect to it. Is there a file that is included to perform the connection? If so, you can simply include the code there. Excluding this sentence, I won't mention that it sounds like your site is in dire need of major refactoring.

Comment: @Webbiedave, Yes I do have a single file that handles the connection, but how can I add logic there that will affect the return values from a SELECT statement on a page that includes it? And yes I know it needs refactoring :). Thanks

Comment: @John - by user's geo location do you mean country or city? which level should determine the returned value?

Comment: @John Isaacks: I see your predicament now. You can't alter the data selected without modifying the query. Sounds like you need to just put in the work to find the queries and change them into a function call so any future changes will be easier. Would it be too laborious to search for the queries?

Comment: @Sandeepan Nath, Region, for example, everyone state that we have a brick and mortal store in, we want to display the same price online as in the store. Then everyone else gets a discounted price.

Comment: @webbiedave, I think I know where most are, I just think it will be a pain, and I am a little afraid of missing one place. I figured this is what I was going to have to do, I was just hoping there was a better option. Thanks!

Comment: @John Isaacks - your question title could also be "implementing user geo-location based data/content display"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not add the detection logic to every page that accesses the data, but to a common page, say index page. Are you having a common page?

Like webbiedave has said, you will have to apply some changes to your query to alter the data.

I have implemented user location based data display in one project. We had to display a list of online classes that will be taken by some tutors. The list of classes is displayed depending on the browser's/registered user's geo-location (country). User region (inside a country I guess) will not change the basic logic for doing this. We also did not use any framework, so I think this may be useful for you:-

This is roughly what we did:-

**1. Geo location manipulation part -**
We have an `index` file (like a front controller of a framework) which is run for every request (for every module) which has all the user geo-location manipulation related code.
Following are the main points about that manipulation code-
- we used a php library to do the detection
- Detect the user location (country in our case) and store it in session.
- Do not detect again/everytime if already stored in session.
- clear stored geo location on user logout and detect again.

**2. Location dependent condition to your queries**
- Now you just have to add the detected location to your query in one place, put it inside a function, add a location parameter to it and call it from your module. Reuse the function as much as possible.